Any way to add samba to ubuntu one pre-built images without using docker
I'm exploring UC24 using a pre-built image on an Intel based SBC with onboard 16GB emmc.
My intended use is a home NAS using the SBC and a USB HD.
I've managed to get it up and running, and using the NextCloud and Jellyfin snaps, I've covered my use cases nearly completely, except for local network file sharing. NextCloud does have webdav support, but that's very slow.
There is no snap for samba, and the only other off the shelf solution I can come up with is to use docker with a samba container. This would work I suspect, but it's an inelegant way to do it, especially since I don't have to use docker for anything else.
Is there any way to sideload samba onto the existing install or any other way to get samba on to the pre-built images or is building my own image the only way? The testing image otherwise covers my use cases so far.
